# translation of forms element with several options

Tags: typo3

Normally i have the label which has only 1 value. How can I define and translate renderables within my kontakt.yaml, which have serveral property options:

```
    properties:
      options:
        Bodenloesungen: Bodenlösungen
        Akustikloesungen: Akustiklösungen
        Holzverarbeitung: Holzverarbeitung
        PR-Anfrage: PR-Anfrage
    type: MultiCheckbox
    identifier: interest
    label: 'Ich interessiere mich für:'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following translation keys can be used to localize option labels in TYPO3's Form Framework:

```
<form-identifier>.element.<element-name>.properties.options.<value>
element.<element-name>.properties.options.<value>
```

So in your case, you could for example use

```
<trans-unit id="element.interest.properties.options.Bodenloesungen">
    <source>soil solution</source>
    <target>Bodenlösungen</target>
</trans-unit>
```

---

You can find a dedicated form translation tutorial with examples here: https://www.sebkln.de/en/tutorials/detail/translating-forms-in-the-typo3-form-framework/

Also, there's an example extension you could play with: https://github.com/sebkln/form_examples

Comment: Thanks, for the quick support. Incidentally i solved the problem a few minutes ago and my solution is not so far away. Your solution safes a lot of space, I must split source and target cause I have one .xlf forboth of them. Nevertheless, kind regards.